# @Fontface on mobile not displaying on moblie

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I am completely baffled by this and I have gone through the previous threads checked all the compliance and still the font is not displaying correctly on mobile.

It works perfectly on desktop.

```
h1 {
  font-family: futura;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 6vw;
 }
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Futura'; /*a name to be used later*/
     src: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/3484f4c3-fd8c-4f1e-8369-372660a87d9f%2FFutura-Display-BQ-Regular.ttf?1550870232783') format('truetype'),
         url('https://cdn.glitch.com/3484f4c3-fd8c-4f1e-8369-372660a87d9f%2FFutura-Display-BQ-Regular.woff?1550870502016') format('woff');/*URL to font*/

}
```

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different name for `font-family`, in both the `@font-face` declaration and in your style definitions (use something other than plain 'Futura'; see https://jsfiddle.net/a8vy7s0c/). There is a family named Futura available locally on iOS, so when that code is run there, it uses the local family rather than the one specified in the `@font-face` declaration.

*P.S. this initially threw me off because I tested the code and saw it 'working', i.e. it was displaying Futura. I thought it was working because I assumed the webfont with Futura in the name would look something like the classic Futura. But it really doesn't look anything like Futura beyond being vaguely sans-serif.*

Comment: You are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all src needed to font face. For example.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyWebFont';
   src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
   src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense. If the correct format is there it should work.